# Initialize RasPi running Ubuntu with separate information (additional user and .bashrc changes)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, raspberry-pi, sd-card

I was wondering of there is a way to initialize a RasPi running Ubuntu with some information before I insert the SD card? Meaning I want to write some default information to the SD card from my local workstation (the one which runs the RasPi Imager). My local workstation is Ubuntu and my RasPi node is Ubuntu as well.

In particular I'm trying to create another user right from the start and manipulate the corresponding .bashrc file. Anyone got an idea on how I could tackle this?

Answer (score 0):

Though I'm not familiar with the Pi, **if** you can make the [Ubuntu *persistent*](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/14912/create-a-persistent-bootable-ubuntu-usb-flash-drive/), i.e., writable so that changes are retained on the card, you could add another user, save changes, and [then diff](https://www.tecmint.com/best-linux-file-diff-tools-comparison/) the changed card with that of a freshly made one. Any changes would be for the additional user (plus any drivers peculiar to your setup that Ubuntu might have downloaded).

Of course, this depends on Pi Ubuntu being made persistent, which might or might not be feasible.